# Method of maintaining read variable during while loop

Tags: bash, scripting, environment-variables

After "Enter server name" and setting the `$servselect` variable in the script below the variable is lost after the "Hello" and "Goodbye" options are selected. This requires completing "Enter server name" prompt again. Is there a way to maintain that variable until the script completely exits? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
while true; do
    read -p "Enter server name: " servselect
    servselect=${servselect:-servselect}
    echo $servselect has been selected!

    printf '%s\n' \
        "" \
        "[A] Hello" \
        "[B] Goodbye" \
        "[Q] Quit" \
        ""
        read -n1 -p 'Enter response here:' response
        case $response in
            [Aa]* )
                printf '%s\n' \
                    "" \
                    "Hello, $servselect" \
                    ""
                    ;;
            [Bb]* )
                printf '%s\n' \
                    "" \
                    "Goodbye, $servselect" \
                    ""
                    ;;
            [Qq]* )
                printf '%s\n' \
                    "" \
                    "Quitting..." \
                    ""
                    break
                    ;;
            * )
                printf '%s\n' \
                    "" \
                    "Please choose A, B, or Q" \
                    ""
                    ;;
        esac
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting it inside the loop, so it will keep prompting you for it.

I would have two loops - one to prompt for the server name and keep prompting until a valid value is provided, and then one to do option A or B or Quit.

For pure programming questions like this, you may be better off asking on stackexchange

Comment: Hey ivanivan, thanks for the response. Do you have an example of how this would function as two separate loops? I can't seem to find an example.

Comment: @hashwagon Something like `while true; do read -p "Enter server name: " servselect; is_valid $servselect && break; echo invalid server name: $servselect; done` for the first loop, and then the same loop as in your question, but without prompting for `servselect`. But in your posted code there is no notion of valid or invalid `servselect`. So maybe you don't care about such validation, and don't need two loops. In that case, simply move the prompting out of the loop, that's all.

Comment: @janos Thank you so much. This worked after adding = after is_valid, e.g., `is_valid=$servselect`.